# log mvc pipeline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, pipeline

I'm using asp.net MVC3 and I need to save in a database all the things that user make in my application (where is each click, IP, date, request, client info).
where during this processing I can replace the default behavior or inject my  own logic?

I noticed that there are ASP.NET MVC extensibility points, I don't know where I have all the data that I need to save in datebase.

Comment: Are you one of the people who refers to IE as "the internet" ? If not, then why are you referring to ASP.NET MVC framework as MVC (which is a language independent design pattern) ?

Comment: sorry @taresko,  I tried to rewrite it clearer

Comment: Make sure that is understood that some buttons clicks handled by javascript will not reach the server. (e.g. a button which just displays a hidden section)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MVC Action Filter Types. references in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I read about Action Filter Context, there are a list which shows the filter event handlers and the context.  Wich is the most suitable in my case?  I must save Ip cliente, user agent, request, datetime, cookies, session id. Also, if I use OutputCacheAttribute, anyway I have to catch the request to save their data.